# How do I make \footcite work in a tabular?

Tags: tables, citing

How do I make \footcite work in a tabular?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % nice tables
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}m{8cm}lm{6cm}@{}} \toprule
  a\footcite{blah} & b & c \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi! With 3.5k rep I would think you knew that a MWE is _necessary_.

Comment: @Jubobs: You're right, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same behavior as for a default footnote:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % nice tables
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}% available for TeXLive/MikTeX
\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}m{8cm}lm{6cm}@{}} \toprule
  a\footnotemark & b & c \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\footcitetext{IEEEexample:masters}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I was using jurabib. In my opinion the approach shown here: http://texblog.org/2012/02/03/using-footnote-in-a-table/ is wider applicable and easier to implement. As I couldn't find anything regarding the `savenotes`environment on stackexchange I thought I leave this link here.

Answer (score 0):

To turn [a previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243852/90570)'s note/link into a proper answer.

You can use the `footnote` package, which provides a `savenotes` environment.  If you put your `tabular` in this environment, the footnote is properly placed.

Here's a MWE based on the OP's example.

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{threeparttable} % nice tables
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}
    \begin{savenotes}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}m{8cm}lm{6cm}@{}}
                \toprule
                a\footcite{blah} & b & c \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{savenotes}
\end{document}
```

And here's what the output looks like (cropped to be concise):

[image: a footnote referenced in a tabular and appearing correctly at the bottom of the page]